# Not getting data from api into the web page, can anyone help me through this where I am getting an error and what can i do to get data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

import React from 'react';

/**

- App
- 
- Simple react js fetch example
  */
  class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

  ```
   super(props);

   this.state = {
       items: [],
       isLoaded: false
   }
  ```

  }

  /**

  - componentDidMount
  - 
  - Fetch json array of objects from given url and update state.
    */
    componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/8260aa5d-8af8-4cff-999e-6e81b217f0ba')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
    this.setState({
    items: json,
    isLoaded: true,
    })
    }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    });

  }

  /**

  - render
  - 
  - Render UI
    */
    render() {

    const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded)
    return Loading...;

    return (

      {items.map(item => (

      Name: {item.name}
    ))}

  );

}

}

export default App;

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

in render function

```
return (
       {
         items.clients.map(item => (<span key={item.id}> Name : {item.name} 
                </span>)
             )
       }
   )
```

Comment: the endpoint of this api is json with a property of    clients that is the array not items itself which is endpoint of api